# R/exams: Negative Points / Deduction not working for incorrect Numeric Answers

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

I created quizzes in r/exams that contain "num" and "string" Answer fields which I am using in Moodle.
I would like to give negative points (e.g. -0.25% of the possible points for that answer) for incorrect answers.
In theory there are functions in r/exams that allow this (exams_eval), but for me they only work in choice questions, not in numeric questions.

I also tried different "rule" settings and variations of the r/exams command but did not got it working. Are negative points not possible for numeric exams?

R/exams Command:

```
exams2moodle("example.Rmd", cloze = list(eval = list(partial = TRUE, rule = "false", negative = -0.25)))
```

Rmd Code (actual code is more complicated, this is just an example for numeric answers):

```
`{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
a <- 1
b <- 2
n = a + b
m = a * b
sol <- c(n, m)
`
Question
========
Calculate the results of the following tasks:  
`r a` + `r b` = ##ANSWER1##  
`r a` * `r b` = ##ANSWER2##  

Solution
========
The solution is:
`r a` + `r b` = `r n`  
`r a` * `r b` = `r m`  

Meta-information
================
extype: cloze
exsolution: `r paste(sol, collapse = "|")`
exclozetype: num|num
extol: 0.01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. Indeed `exams2moodle()` should be improved to throw a warning in case of such an `eval` specification. (Incidentally we just discussed this among the authors earlier this week.)

To the best of my knowledge it is not possible to assign negative points to `num` or `string` elements within `cloze` exercises. If you look at the official documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Embedded_Answers_(Cloze)_question_type#Syntax_for_numerical_Cloze_questions you see that it is discussed how to provide a feedback text in case of a wrong answer. But this is always associated with 0%. If you just enter something like -25% in the corresponding embedded answer, this can be imported into Moodle but is actually ignored.

The only parameter that might be useful is the `penalty` argument - but I'm not sure how this works in Moodle. It is easy to specify in `exams2moodle()` and in the Moodle XML code but I couldn't find examples for the effects this has in a Moodle quiz.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I played a bit with the penalty tag in the XML (still have to understand the use of the penalty argument since it is in make_question_moodle), but i did not see an effect so far. If i find a solution i will tell

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! This matches my experience with the penalty tag...also couldn't find out what this is really useful for.

Comment: Now I found some documentation of the penalty factor - not specifically for cloze questions but for multiple-choice questions: <https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Multiple_Choice_question_type#Penalty_factor>. This says that the penalty factor is only applied in adaptive mode when participants can answer each question multiple times. But this is not what you intend, I guess, because you want to apply the question only once but still use the penalty factor.